# How can I send a file from the server to client using REST (JAX-RS Jersey)?

Tags: file, rest, jersey, ejb, jax-rs

I want to send a file from my server side (EJB) using REST Jersey (JAX-RS).

I am trying with the following code,

```
Public Response getFiles() {
  File file = new File(fileName);
  FileOutputStream dest = new FileOutputStream(file);
  ZipOutputStream out =  new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(dest));
  out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(fileName));
  final ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok(out);
  response.header("Content-Type", "*/*");
  response.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.getName() + ".zip");
  return response.build();
}
```

But I am getting the exception message

```
type class java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream, and MIME media type */* was not found
SEVERE: The registered message body writers compatible with the MIME media type are:
```

Also tried with `"Content-Type" , "application/octet-stream", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` and `multipart/form-data`

But none of them is working.

Answer (score 0):

Use `application/zip`.

```
@GET
@Produces("application/zip")
public Response getZip() {
    final File f = new File("/tmp/foo.zip");
    ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok((Object) f);
    response.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + f.getName());
    return response.build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

application/octet-stream + gzip

```
@GET
@Path("/getFiles")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
public Response getFiles() {
    StreamingOutput stream = new StreamingOutput() {
        @Override
        public void write(OutputStream output) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
            String filePath = "/yourFile.pdf";
            java.nio.file.Path path = Paths.get(filePath);
            byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
            output.write(data);
            output.flush();
        }
    };
    return Response.ok(stream).build();
}
```

and a jersey filter added to web.xml

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters</param-name>
    <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.GZIPContentEncodingFilter</param-value>
</init-param>
```

when making the request:

send a header of "Accept" with value of "application/octet-stream"
and a header of "Accept-Encoding" with value of "gzip"